# Unknown custom element even it declear in component section in vue

Tags: vue.js

In vue, why `my-comp` doesn't render and I get this error?

```
Unknown custom element: <my-comp> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

This is how foo.vue looks like:

```
<template functional>
  <div>
    <my-comp>
      <div>something</div>
    </my-comp>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import MyComp from './my-comp.vue';

export default {
  components: { 'my-comp': MyComp },
};
</script>
```

`my-comp`:

```
<template functional>
  <div class="my-comp">
    <h3>{{ props.name }}</h3>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'my-comp',
};
</script>
```

it because `functional`? how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information why you are using the `functional` attribute?
The error you're getting is definitely because of that.

Try to register component globally in your `main.js` or `app.js` file. Like so: 
`Vue.component('MyComp', require('./components/MyComp.vue').default);`

Another, "ugly" approach without registering the component globally, would look something like this:

```
<template functional>
  <div>
    <component :is="props.components.MyComp"> <!-- works with <my-comp> tag as well -->
      <div>something</div>
    </component>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import MyComp from './my-comp.vue';

export default {
  props: {
    components: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {
          MyComp
        };
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

A little bit prettier code approach than the one above, is to use injections. It could look something like this:

```
<template functional>
  <div>
    <component :is="injections.components.MyComp">
      <div>something</div>
    </component>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import MyComp from './my-comp.vue';

export default {
    inject: {
      components: {
        default: {
          MyComp
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: cause I don't need to use script tag in my components, I can access `props` from the template.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Maybe it could be something you're looking for.

Comment: but what if I use v-for in the parent component? it will register the component many times.

Comment: Do you mean the parent component `foo.vue`? In that component, you can remove `import MyComp from './my-comp.vue';` and `components: { 'my-comp': MyComp }` if `MyComp` is registered globally. Or maybe I misunderstood your statement?

Comment: Not sure I want that component global. I use that component only in one module/page

Comment: I have added another suggestion. Take a look. It's ugly, but that is a working workaround without having to register the component globally.